# Where can I ask questions about the game Counter Strike?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Is Counter Strike Global Offensive on topic on any site within Stack Exchange?

If yes, I assume it would be in the Sports Stack Exchange?

Comment: Why would you assume it would be Sports?

Comment: @ale because its esports

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can post CS:GO questions on  [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)  (Gaming Stack Exchange) with the tag [[counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go)].